# How to shortened my JQ Script

Tags: jquery

I write some JQ Script for append new display name option on front-end like wp back-end. Select with ID #display_name will auto add new option when #nickname, #last_name or  #nickname change value.

And it works ok!

But my code so long.

How to shortened my JQ Script below?

```
       var nickname     = jQuery('#nickname');
       var first_name   = jQuery('#first_name');
       var last_name    = jQuery('#last_name');
           nickname.change(function() {

               jQuery('#display_name').append($('<option>', { 
                                        value: nickname.val(),
                                        text : nickname.val() 
                                    }));
           });
           first_name.change(function() {

               jQuery('#display_name').append($('<option>', { 
                                        value: first_name.val(),
                                        text : first_name.val() 
                                    }));
                jQuery('#display_name').append($('<option>', { 
                                        value: last_name.val() +' '+ first_name.val(),
                                        text : last_name.val() +' '+ first_name.val()
                                    }));
                jQuery('#display_name').append($('<option>', { 
                                        value: first_name.val() +' '+ last_name.val(),
                                        text : first_name.val() +' '+ last_name.val()
                                    }));
           });
           last_name.change(function() {

               jQuery('#display_name').append($('<option>', { 
                                        value: last_name.val(),
                                        text : last_name.val() 
                                    }));
                jQuery('#display_name').append($('<option>', { 
                                        value: last_name.val() +' '+ first_name.val(),
                                        text : last_name.val() +' '+ first_name.val()
                                    }));
                jQuery('#display_name').append($('<option>', { 
                                        value: first_name.val() +' '+ last_name.val(),
                                        text : first_name.val() +' '+ last_name.val()
                                    }));
           });
```

Comment: this question belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ...

Comment: Thank you & Sorry!. Can you move this post to that? :(
Because I'm do it for wordpress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your shortened code

```
$("#nickname,#first_name,#last_name").change(function () {
  $('#display_name').append($('<option>', {
    value: $(this).val(),
    text: $(this).val()
  }));
  if ($(this).attr("id") != "nickname") {
    var first_name = jQuery('#first_name');
    var last_name = jQuery('#last_name');
    $('#display_name').append($('<option>', {
        value: last_name.val() + ' ' + first_name.val(),
        text: last_name.val() + ' ' + first_name.val()
    })).append($('<option>', {
        value: first_name.val() + ' ' + last_name.val(),
        text: first_name.val() + ' ' + last_name.val()
    }));
  }
});
```

working **DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/WcjLW/

Comment: Thank you very much! It very short and works fine! ;)

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do is cache your selectors and use `e.target` for the check condition

```
  var $display = jQuery('#display_name');

  $('#nickname, #first_name, #last_name').on('change', function (e) {
      var firstName = jQuery('#first_name').val(),
          lastName = jQuery('#last_name').val(),
          fullName = firstName + ' ' + lastName,
          revFullName = lastName + ' ' + firstName,
          options = [];

      options.push(this.value);

      if (e.target.id !== 'nickname') {
          options.push(revFullName, fullName);
      }
      $display.empty();
      $.each(options, function (i, val) {
          $display.append($('<option>', {
              value: val,
              text: val
          }));
      });
  });
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WcjLW/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

making a function to add a display option helps a lot:

```
function addDisplayOption(value, text){
    jQuery('#display_name').append($('<option>', { 
        value: value,
        text : text 
    }));
}
```

if you bundle together what is the same you can shorten your code to:

```
var nickname     = jQuery('#nickname');
var first_name   = jQuery('#first_name');
var last_name    = jQuery('#last_name');

function addDisplayOption(value, text){
    jQuery('#display_name').append($('<option>', {
        value: value,
        text : text
    }));
}

function showDisplayOptions(){
    addDisplayOption(first_name.val(), first_name.val());
    addDisplayOption(last_name.val() +' '+ first_name.val(),last_name.val() +' '+ first_name.val())
    addDisplayOption(first_name.val() +' '+ last_name.val(),first_name.val() +' '+ last_name.val())
}


nickname.change(function() {
    addDisplayOption(nickname.val(),nickname.val())
});

first_name.change(showDisplayOptions);
last_name.change(showDisplayOptions);
```